# VBA concatenate two ranges and create new range in VBA

Tags: vba

Is it possible to create a new range that concatenates the 3 ranges together into a new range? For example, the first value of the range would be `The-Ball-Park` and the second value would be `The-Train-Station`, so on and so forth over X amount of rows. If possible, I would like it so script would skip over completely blank rows.

I would like to save the range into a variable, I would **Not** like to have the range be inserted in the sheet.

Thank you!

| Key1 | Key2 | Key3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| The | Ball | Park |
| The | Train | Station |
| The | Fast | Lane |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to make it a bit more clever if you don't intend on using exactly 3 inputs for each output.
Let me know.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Sub ConcatRangeToArray()
    
    'Variables
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim OG_Array
    Dim Output_Array
    Dim RG As Range
    
    'Set this to whatever range you need concatenated
    Set RG = Sheet1.Range("A2:C4")  '<<< range to concatenate
    OG_Array = RG
    ReDim Output_Array(1 To UBound(OG_Array, 1))
    
    'Preform concatenation
    For I = 1 To UBound(OG_Array, 1)
        Output_Array(I) = OG_Array(I, 1) & "-" & OG_Array(I, 2) & "-" & OG_Array(I, 3)
        Debug.Print Output_Array(I)
    Next I

End Sub
```

Example of spreadsheet I used:

[image: Example of spreadsheet]

Example of output:

[image: Output Example]